# Description of a chapter in a page

Tags: sectioning, chapters, description

I would like to decorate my headlines (section, subsection, etc.) by adding foreach a chapter a description area.

This picture is a screenshot document where the headline has the formating, layout and color I want.[image]

How I can achieve this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing what you have so far. Unless  we know the basic set up you are using, the best anybody can do is guess what might work. The answer depends, for example, on the class you are using and any relevant packages. Moreover, your question leaves all the work to the community - even setting up the basic framework of your document and filling it with some dummy text. Help us to help you by providing people with a place to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [fncychap](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/fncychap/fncychap.pdf) package.

You can build your own chapter-styles:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lettrine}


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\sffamily}
  {\flushright\fontsize{90}{0}\textbf{\textcolor{black!20}{\thechapter}}}{10pt}
  {\flushright\fontsize{30}{0}\textbf{#1}\vskip80pt\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{-40pt}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}

\lettrine[lines=4]{\color{black!20}S} tart of the chapter. \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]